# In highcharts horizontal bar chart, I can't display the default ticks

Tags: highcharts, label, horizontal-line

This is the graph code in javascript:

```
Highcharts.chart(here, {
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
            type: "bar",
            //width: 300,
            //height: 60,
            width: 800,
            height: 160,
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Default category name"],
            title: {
                text: "testo uno"
            },
            //labels: {
            //    enabled: true
            //},
            opposite: true,
            tickInterval: 1
        },
        yAxis: {
            max: maximum,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: "testo due"
            }
            //labels: {
            //    enabled: true
            // }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            valueSuffix: " millions"
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointPadding: 0.3,
                groupPadding: 0.1,
                animation: false
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: "Name number one",
                data: [v1],
                color: "rgb(251, 147, 53)"
            },
            {
                name: "Name number two",
                data: [v2],
                color: "rgb(128, 128, 128)"
            },
            {
                name: "Name number three",
                data: [v3],
                color: "rgb(137, 196, 76)"
            }
        ]
    });
```

I want the default ticks' labels to be displayed on top. I can't seem to get those, I tried setting labels{enabled} to false, and some other things but I can't seem to get the ticks' labels display on top. Please look the attached screenshot to see where I want the ticks to be. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Vladimir, will you create a codepen like thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make space for the labels, for example by keeping the default margin and set `yAxis.opposite` to true.

In API we can read:

> **margin: number, Array.**
>
> ...
>
> By default there is no margin. The actual space is dynamically
> calculated from the offset of axis labels, axis title, title, subtitle
> and legend in addition to the spacingTop, spacingRight, spacingBottom
> and spacingLeft options.

```
    yAxis: {
        opposite: true,
        ...
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9rgjdesw/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.margin

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.opposite